# Reading a file and calling another .bat from within a Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder c:\Scripts.
I put in three files in there:

```
build.txt
trigger.bat
deploy.bat
```

I have a build number inside my `build.txt` Something like

```
1.2.3.4
```

I am trying to pass the version incremented by one every day in an automated fashion. So, today my .txt file has 1.2.3.4, my trigger.bat will have to call the deploy.bat with a command line argument 1.2.3.5 (incremented by 1). It should also overwrite my .txt file content with 1.2.3.5 because I am gonna schedule it. So, tomorrow, it will auto increment to 1.2.3.6 and so on.

Right now with I have this inside my `trigger.bat`:

```
@echo off
set /p build=<version.txt
FOR /f "tokens=4* delims=." %%a IN ("%build%") DO (
set ver=%%a
)
set /A ver=ver+1
.\deploy.bat -version "1.2.3.%ver%"
```

I have two issues there:

1. I do not know how to increment so I delimited the version, trying to get the last digit and increment it and then concatenate to pass with my version. It is the worst way anyone could ever do I guess. I need some help here on how I can increment it.
2. How do I overwrite the text file? So, if I can get some help with the incremented value then I guess, I can just do a `echo %version% > version.txt` I assume that will overwrite my text file. If not, please help with this too.

I am ok with PowerShell solution too. It is just that I know some basics with Windows batch scripting so I opted that route.

Comment: After version 1.2.3.9, will you go to 1.2.3.10 or 1.2.4.0?

Comment: according to standard versioning rules, it's 1.2.3.10 (which sadly makes it hard to sort or compare)

Comment: Yep, it is 1.2.3.10 after 1.2.3.9.

Comment: In your code `set /p build=<version.txt` you actually mean `set /p build=<build.txt`, right? are you using two names for the same text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) to inrease, you *have* to disassemble it. So your approach goes into the right direction. Just extend it a bit to make it more flexible:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p build=<version.txt
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ("%build%") do (
  set /a last=%%d + 1
  set ver=%%a.%%b.%%c.!last!
)
echo %ver% > version.txt
.\deploy.bat -version "%ver%"
```

2) correct, `>` overwrites the destination file (or creates it, if it doesn't exist). (`>>` would append)

Comment: Hi Stephan, thank you! I have one question. It is a 10 day sprint. So after every 10 day it will have to change the 3rd digit. For example, it will be 1.2.3.1, 1.2.3.2, 1.2.3.3, 1.2.3.4, .... up to 1.2.3.10. And on the 11th day it will be a new sprint that i, 1.2.4.1. Is there any way to manipulate this 10 days from a batch script? may be from the last digits of the version? when it becomes 10, I should not make it 1.2.3.11 but 1.2.4.1. Thank you!

Comment: based on Day-10 or based on version number? Both is possible, but the how-to will be completely different.

Comment: @BhavaniKannan, in case incrementing the third partial number of the version string is to be done by *date*, I would do that in a separate batch script and schedule that accordingly, because date maths is not native to batch scripting; e. g., every day at `08:00`, `trigger.bat` runs, and every 10th day at `07:50`, the new script runs...

Comment: @aschipfl exactly what I thought `:)`. In case of "based on version number" a simple `if !ver! gtr 10` plus another variable for the third token should do.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, guys! :)

Comment: you're welcome. Please ask a new question, if you have more problems.

Answer (score 1):

Why reading the file content into a variable first to parse it by `for /F`? You can immediately read the file by `for /F`. With the `>` redirection operator you can overwrite the text file finally.

Here is the updated code of the batch script `trigger.bat`:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "FILE=%~dp0build.txt"

for /F "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=." %%A in ("%FILE%") do (
    set "VER=%%A" & set "MAJ=%%B" & set "MIN=%%C" & set "BLD=%%D"
    set /A "BLD+=1"
    rem // Rules for incrementing the numeric parts:
    if !BLD! GTR 10 (set /A "BLD=1, MIN+=1")
    set "VERSION=!VER!.!MAJ!.!MIN!.!BLD!"
)
> "%FILE%" echo %VERSION%

call "%~dp0deploy.bat" -version "%VERSION%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

To call the other batch file `deploy.bat` you should use the `call` command to return to this batch file afterwards. The `%~dp0` prefix tells the script to search for `deploy.bat` in the parent directory of this script, `trigger.bat` (`C:\Scripts\` in your case), opposed to `.\`, meaning to search the current working directory. Particularly when you are running `trigger.bat` by Windows Task Scheduler, I assume the default working directory might be something like `%SystemRoot%\System32`.